# Javascript use RegEXP to remove characters between (but not including) special characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing

I have a string as follows:

```
var s = "1111 type reallycoolsentence\text.json\n1111 type anotherreallycoolsentence text2.json
```

I'm trying to get rid of the characters between the backslashes.

Wanted result:

```
s = "type reallycoolsentence\\type anotherreallycoolsentence"
```

I know how to remove everything except characters between two special characters WITHOUT removing the special characters. Every answer on stack includes removing them too :(

Comment: `\b` for a word boundary would allow you to find the start of the filename

Comment: please add the wanted result and your try.

Comment: If you get rid of `\n` you will be left with only one backslash character...

Comment: edited  to reflect that thanks

Comment: Why is `n1111` missing in the example result? It's not between the backslashes.

Comment: Your description of what you're trying to do doesn't seem to match the result. Why is `text2.json` removed in addition to the text between the backslashes?

Comment: Do you really have backslashes in the original string? In a JavaScript string literal, `\t` means TAB, `\n` means newline.

Comment: its the way JSON.stringify'd the file. i was able to remove the other unwanted characters

Comment: In general you shouldn't perform operations on the JSON. You should use `JSON.parse()` to convert it back into data, and then process that.

Comment: After parsing, what you want to remove is everything between `\t` and `\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the backslashes in the replacement string.

Note that you need to double them to get literal backslashes because backslash is an escape prefix in string literals.

```js
var s = "1111 type reallycoolsentence\\text.json\\n1111 type anotherreallycoolsentence text2.json";
var result = s.replace(/\\.*\\/, '\\\\');
console.log(result);
```

This result doesn't match the result in your example, but that's because it doesn't match your description of what you want to do. I implemented the description.

Answer (score 1):

For those of us who don't like regex...:

```
  s = "1111 type reallycoolsentence text.json\n1111 type anotherreallycoolsentence text2.json"
  wArray = s.split(" ");  
  wArray = wArray.filter( value => value !== "1111");
  wArray = wArray.filter(value => !value.includes('.json'));
  result = wArray.join(" ");
```

Output:

```
type reallycoolsentence type anotherreallycoolsentence
```

Comment: Why doesn't the code have any reference to backslashes?

Comment: @Barmar It doesn't need to; once the string is split into a list, the list elements which contain a backslash are filtered out, as they are part of the element containing `.json`..

Comment: Where does the question say anything about filtering out the part containing `.json`?

Comment: @Barmar It said that at the time I wrote the answer "Im trying to get rid of ... [filename].json". It's been edited out since then.

Comment: I see -- they've completely changed the question, except for the example result.

Comment: Yes, that's one of the problem with this current SO system: a question is presented, you provide an answer and then, later, the question is modified - sometimes so extensively that you don't even recognize it anymore; and your answer becomes useless. I don't always have the time (or inclination) to go and chase those changes...